# Configure Local Repository in Sourcetree

Tags: git, sourcetree

Using Sourcetree and Git, by Default, when I check out from development branch, the code is getting check out under /Documents [Windows 7]. Is there a way to configure this path, so that I can check out the code to my_preferred_Drive:/my_preferred_folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is checked out at the location where you first cloned the project.
When cloning a project you can specify the `destination path` at which you want to clone the project. At this point you can enter `my_preferred_Drive:/my_preferred_folder` in the Destination Path Field

[image]

When you checkout anything after this, it will be checked out at this destination location

Comment: Except that... it doesn't work.  I just cloned a project to c:\workspace\test1, then I clone again, it shows  v:\My Documents\.... as default destination path.  It invariably returns to  v:\My Documents\.